# Georeferenced black and white maps showing up as mostly transparent and very low resolution once exported from MXD to KMZ

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, export, georeferencing, google-earth

I exported .pngs from a simple black and white pdf map, georeferenced them in ArcMap 10.3.1 and then wanted to export them KMZ. However, upon opening my kml, the maps have become mostly transparent, and any black lines have become very low resolution.

See attached images for the original B&W and the resulting layer in the KMZ (viewed in google earth).

[image: Original Black and White PNG I exported from a PDF]
[image: Post georeferencing and exported from mxd to kmz, viewed in google earth]

Comment: in google earth go to the layer and set "clamp to ground" or use this option in exporting to kmz https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/kml-conversion.htm

Comment: I have been toggling the option in ArcMap; I know it's clamping because when I turn on the terrain layer in google earth, it molds to the varying surface.

Comment: The altitudeMode (clampToGround) is good to check, but I suspect this might be about the image being exported with transparency. Can you unzip the KMZ, pull the image out, and see if it contains the transparency?  If so, then you're not exporting correctly from Arc... it's probably applying transparency to white or some "no data" value.  See if Arc has a setting to control the "no data" value or color, and turn it off, or select something that's not your white background.